# number of subgraphs is 8 , but I only get 7

Tags: graph-theory

[image: graph]

Assuming that vertex 'a' is removed, we are apparently left with 2^3 possible subgraphs. However I see only 7. They are listed here :

b,c,d,

b,c

b,d

c,d

b

c

d

unless we add Ø as a subgraph.

Can we add the null subgraph Ø as a subgraph, or is there another subgraph that I've missed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The empty graph is always a subgraph, so it definitely should be included. Given there are no edges once you remove $a$ and its adjacent edges, it reduces to counting subsets of the remaining vertex set $\{b, c, d\}$. There are $2^3$ subsets (empty set included) of a $3$ element set.

Comment: @TheoBendit Saying that it is *always* a subgraph is too strong; many authors require a graph to have at least one vertex, because so many things go wrong with the $0$-vertex graph. But certainly if there are $8$ subgraphs, then that's what being counted.

Comment: Thank you , @MishaLavrov

Comment: Thank you @TheoBendit